# Windows 7 Pro - "domain" like login screen appeared

Tags: windows-7, login, login-screen

I'm setting up a new PC with the Windows 7 Pro. After some actions (software installing, config changes, applying updates ), my login screen looks like the PC is connected to the domain:

[image]

[image]

I have checked the settings and everywhere the "workgroup" is checked.
I have been googling for three hours trying some solutions (Control UserPasswords2, regedit and the ".DEFAULT" key) but nothing works. I cannot see the user icons - only the login screen as above. I cannot also change the account icon.

Has anybody seen such an issue?

Comment: The host most have been on a domain before... its just remembering ... from the registry http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737 and it probably still has gpo settings from when it was on a domain or local group policy was adjusted. If it was never on a domain, then it never was and should not act like it has

Comment: Well, as I'm the only person who uses this PC since its beginning (one day) I know it has never been connected to a domain. What I configured is the PC name and the ID wizard ("My computer" properties), where I selected "Company network" without the domain access.

Thanks for the link you posted, but my intention is to show up the users names&icons (as on the classic "workgroup" login screen).

Anybody knows where the login screen checks if it is connected to a domain, or to a workgroup?

Comment: If its showing it has been on a domain like you said, then its because it was on a domain once before. Only way that information gets there is because it was put on a domain by someone. OR it could have been sysprep'd unattend.xml via the mini setup and all that information could be added when you first ran it the first time.

Comment: Is any of the Windows Updates being known to cause such an issue? Because as I remember, the problem showed up after applying several dozen of them (a set installed at one go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved!

The reason was the *Dell Data Protection | Access* software installed by default. The solution was to disable it via its settings - now I can see all the other local accounts and their icons, like you see when connected to a workgroup.

As I now know what was responsible for the issue, I can set it like I want to.
The problem begun when, I think, I had changed the login rules via this Dell app.

I do appreciate your help and concepts. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

It could also be caused by a Group Policy. I don't have my Windows 7 machine handy, but I will update the instructions Tuesday when I'm at work...

1. Login as an Administrative user
2. Click Start, type `gpedit.msc` and press Enter. You may be prompted with a User Account Control dialog, just choose **Yes**
3. Navigate to *Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Local Policies\Security Options*. On the left there is an option labelled *Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DELETE* that you can disable.
4. As well (and this is probably the one), go to Start, type `regedit` and press Enter. Again, click **Yes** if prompted. Navigate to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System!LogonType`. This should be switched from 1 to 0 (or vice versa, I'll have to doublecheck) to change the type. It's also under the policy editor from above, under the guise of `Always use classic logon`. I don't know which key though.

These effects claim to take effect immediately, but I'd still recommend doing a proper shutdown and reboot.

Comment: Thank you - here is the report:

1) Under the gpedit.msc, changing the [i]Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DELETE[/i] option only changes the requirement to press the CTRL+ALT+DEL buttons. No matter if I use or not this setting, the only change is to press or not to press. The login screen stays the same.

2) About the registry action, I haven't found such a value there. I've tried a DWORD value with both 1 or 0 setting, but it didn't change anything. Restarts were performed after each value change.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `Secure logon` may have been enabled by a Windows update.

To remove the effect, click on Windows logo, type `User Accounts`, click the `Manage User Accounts` link.

Select "Advanced" tab, under Secure Logon, untick the `Require users...` and click OK (screenshot below).

[image: UserAccounts-SecureLogon]

Comment: Under my system, this option is unfortunately grayed out - I cannot tick or untick this.

Comment: Ticked but grayed out or not ticked?

Comment: Try this [Fix it 50406](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308226) from MS, download the Disable one, then right click `Run as administrator`, reboot when done. Also tried to change the workgroup to something else? Otherwise, is it fine if you make your account to be auto logon?

Comment: Also try change this registry to `1` and reboot: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\DisableCAD`

Comment: Patric is partially right. That registry key controls the "local" value for this setting. However. if there's a group policy defined for the setting, (see the Canadian Luke's answer) this overrides the "local" setting. Your options in that case are 1) change the setting through the `gpedit.msc` as described in that answer 2) delete the key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System!DisableCAD`. This will make the policy editor setting say `Not Defined` instead of `Enabled` or `Disabled` which will once again let you edit the setting as described in *this* answer.